# python script how to handle second shell and enter command in that shell

Tags: python, shell

I want to use python achieve following process:

```
[zz@bts01 ~]$ cd /opt/cdma-msc/
[zz@bts01 cdma-msc]$ ./sccli
SoftCore for CDMA CLI (c) Quortus 2010
RAN> show system
System Configuration
  Software version:      V1.31
  System name:           RAN
  System location:
  Shutdown code:
  Emergency call dest:
  Current date/time:     Tue Feb 27 14:27:41 2018
  System uptime:         20h 33m
  Auto-provisioning:     Enabled
RAN> exit
Bye.
[zz@bts01 cdma-msc]$
```

Please see above, I want to use python to call this  /opt/cdma-msc/rancli process, which will open a secondary shell, and I want to capture the output of command "show license" in that shell. How can I achieve this in python?
I tried with subprocess Popen, and was able to call the shell, but cannot enter anything into it. Anyone have some thought?

```
ran = subprocess.Popen(['/opt/cdma-msc/sccli'], shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
hnb = subprocess.Popen(['show system'],stdin=ran.stdout )
```

above is the python module/command I tried, apparently the second line didn't take the output from first, casue it is calling another shell.

Comment: Show the code which didn't work so we can see where you got it wrong.

Comment: I add two command I tried with python subprocess module, I am not sure am I on the right track.

Comment: The "shell" created by the CLI is not a "command shell" in the sense you imagine. It's just an interactive REPL, not a process which communicates with the calling shell's process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the command to be the input to the subprocess you created, not the name of a new subprocess.

If you have a new enough Python, try

```
output = subprocess.run(['/opt/cdma-msc/sccli'],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    input='show system',
    check=True, universal_newlines=True).stdout
```

The result returned by `run` is an object which encapsulates the result code and status of the subprocess as well as the output from it. Its `stdout` member contains the text produced on standard output.

Unfortunately, `run` was only introduced in Python 3.5 but it's enough of an improvement that you might want to not support older versions of Python. If you have to support older versions, the equivalent code is considerably clunkier:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/opt/cdma-msc/sccli'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate('show system')
```

Here, `stdout` is simply a string with the output.

You should generally avoid raw `Popen()` unless the higher-level wrappers absolutely cannot do what you want. There is  also obviously no need for `shell=True` when there are no wildcards, pipelines, rediections, or even argument parsing (you already broke the command line into a list of strings).

Comment: Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: Hi tripleee, for some reason I cannot update the python to latest. I only got python2.7 on this machine. Is there a alternative for above command in python2.7?

Comment: Updated for 2.7 as well, code from memory but you shoud easily find similar examples if there are typos or I forgot a parameter.

Comment: Maybe also check if the CLI accepts command-line arguments so you don't need to talk to its `stdin` at all in batch mode; that's just a complication really.

Comment: Hi Triplee, thank you so much for your help. Actually I just found I am using python2.6.6 instead of 2.7, but I upgrade it to 2.7 and still got some errors.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hnbtest.py", line 25, in <module>
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 211, in check_output
    raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
ValueError: stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.

Comment: Sorry I haven't had the time to get back to you properly today. I *think* you can fix it by changing `check_output` to `Popen` but I'll try to verify when I have more time.

Comment: @Weiqi Updated now, sorry for the long delay.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! Appreciate! @tripleee